# jQuery count number of li's in each ul

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a width to LI elements based on how many li's there are e.g.

- first li has 5 children so width  of children should be 20%
- second li has 4 children so width of children should be 25%;
- third li has 6 children so width of children should be 19%

I have got part way there with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var count = $('#main-menu li ul > li').size();
 var width = 100/count;
 $('header nav#main-menu li ul li').css("width",width+"%");
});
```

The problem it's counting all the elements in total (including children). Is this possible?

Comment: `size()` is a deprecated method. http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: please share the html sample

Comment: `var count = $('#main-menu li ul > li').length;`

Comment: 4 is 25%, and 5 is 20%, how does 6 become 19% ??

Comment: @adeneo just bad math, I guess...

Comment: @adeneo fingers too quick for my brain, meant to be 16% :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.each($('#main-menu li ul'), function() {
       var children = $(this).find(">li");
       var count = children.length;
       var width = 100/count;
       children.css("width", width + "%");
   });
});
```

Comment: I think what Alnitak is referring to is that if you have nested lists, you'll get them all with find().

Comment: Ahhh, then .find(">li") will solve that easily :) Answer changed.

Comment: that's not my point - `.find()` will keep on recursing down the tree of `ul li` elements (should it have more than one level) and incorrectly count grand-children etc as well as children.  If you specifically only want direct descendants, use `.children` and not `.find`

Comment: Fair enough point, changed to ">li" which is actually still more efficient (oddly!).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$('#main-menu li ul').each(function() {
    var $children = $(this).children('li');
    var count = children.length;
    if (count) {
        $children.css('width', 100 / count + '%');
    }
});
```